# How do i determine the dipole moment of a charged conducting sphere in a uniform electric field?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, dipole-moment

What bugs me the most is that since there is net charge, i dont know two things, how would that charge distribute across the surface (even though my intuition says that one of the sides will have more charge than the other) and how would one calculate the dipole moment since the distribution wouldn't be symmetrical about the X-axis (in this problem the equator of the sphere), i've found the potential around it via legendre polynomials which i guess could help, but i just... dont really have a good idea of what to do neither the confidence

Comment: *I've found the potential.* The surface charge density is proportional to the field at the surface, which you can determine from the gradient of the potential.

Comment: ok sure... then what's the constant of proportionality i need to know/find? @Ghoster

Comment: See pages 17 and 18 of [this PDF](https://physics.unm.edu/Courses/Roy/PHYC161FA16/Lecture14.pdf). Surely your textbook covers how the charge density on the surface of a conductor is related to the field just outside the conductor. It’s one of the standard applications of Gauss’ Law.